# TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python

```
def PonerFecha():
    year=int(input('Digite el año: '))
    month=int(input('Digite el mes: '))
    day=int(input('Digite el dia: '))
    FechaNueva=(year,month,day)
    for j in range (len(matchs)-1):
        if matchs[j]<matchs[j+1]:
            tmp=matchs[j]
            matchs[j] = matchs[j+1]
            matchs[j+1]=tmp
    return FechaNueva

def EntrarDatos():
    GolRival=int(input('Digite los goles del equipo rival: '))
    GolesUnab=int(input('Digite los goles de la UNAB:'))
    Datos=(GolRival,GolesUnab)
    return Datos

matchs=[]
while True:
    menu()
    try:
        opcion=int(input('Ingrese el numero de la opcion escogida: '))
    except:
        opcion==-1
    if opcion==1:
        matchs.append(PonerFecha(),EntrarDatos())
        print(matchs)
    elif opcion==2:
         OrdenarPartidos()
```

Necesito que ciertos datos se guarden dentro de la lista, con las fechas sirve bien pero con la otra funcion de los goles, me aparece ese error,no estoy seguro de como solucionarlo, lo estuve intentando de diferentes formas y ninguno me sirvio.
Gracias
Se guardan de esta manera

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

Pero necesito que se guarden asi:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: por favor indenta bien tu codigo

Comment: en primer lugar los datos que te retorna `PonerFecha()` y `EntrarDatos()` son tuplas, y al hacer el `append()` quedaria algo asi `matchs.append((y,m,d),(gol1,gol2))` y no puedes agregar 2 tuplas a una lista, tendrias que hacer `matchs.append([PonerFecha(),EntrarDatos()])`

Comment: Necesito que se guarden en la misma lista estos dos

Comment: Ahora hago una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para obtener ambos datos en una sola tupla, lo único que se tiene que hacer es sumar ambos y listo!, esto combinará sus elementos en una sola tupla.

```py
    ...
    if opcion==1:
        matchs.append(PonerFecha()+EntrarDatos())
        print(matchs)
```

Una cosa que haces mal es tu bloque `except` pues estas usando el operador de comparación (`==`) `opcion==-1` y debería ser el de asignación (`=`) `opcion=-1`, pero yo recomiendo cambiarlo por un `continue` así el bucle volverá al principio y se le pedirá nuevamente el dato al usuario.

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo dice en el mensaje list.append solo necesita un argumento y has puesto dos. Las listas le puedes añadir los items con append pero de 1 en 1.
Asi que cambia la linea

```
matchs.append(PonerFecha(),EntrarDatos())
```

Por estas dos

```
matchs.append(PonerFecha())
matchs.append(EntrarDatos())
```

Con eso los datos los añades a la lista matchs.